# Firebase Cloud Messaging topic send, message does not show in Notifications and is never sent

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using the REST api and I am trying to send to a topic. I know the topic exists because I can see in the Notification console that the topic is there. And I can send a test message through the console and that works.

However, when I use the REST api, I get an http status 200 response with json {"message_id":8769790390495267408} which looks like a successful send. However, the message does not show up in Notifications and the message is not sent to subscribed clients.

My message looks like, which is from the docs

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
  "data": {
    "message": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
   }
}
```

And I am using the "Server key" and  not the Web api key.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sending this to a device? Android or iOS?

Comment: To devices subscribed to the topic. iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For iOS, try using `notification` instead of `data`. Then add in the `priority` and set it to `high`. The payload should look something like this:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{
  "to": "/topics/foo-bar",
  "priority": "high",
  "notification" : {
      "body" : "great match!",
      "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "icon" : "myicon"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had switched to notification since originally posting. You were right on, the priority was what was needed. This wasn't clear to me from documentation.